# Deploy storybook along with CRA on google cloud app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, create-react-app, storybook

I'm trying to deploy the storybook also along with my create react app on google cloud app engine using the following configuration:

```
runtime: nodejs14
service: inkse-ui-staging
handlers:
  - url: /storybook/static
    static_dir: storybook-static/static
    expiration: "0m"
    secure: always

  - url: /storybook/(.*\.(json|ico|js|png))$
    static_files: storybook-static/\1
    upload: storybook-static/.*\.(json|ico|js|png)$
    expiration: "0m"
    secure: always

  - url: /storybook/.*
    static_files: storybook-static/index.html
    upload: storybook-static/index.html
    expiration: "0m"
    secure: always

  - url: /static
    static_dir: build/static
    expiration: "0m"
    secure: always

  - url: /(.*\.(json|ico|js|png))$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*\.(json|ico|js|png)$
    expiration: "0m"
    secure: always

  - url: .*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
    expiration: "0m"
    secure: always
```

But it always renders the build content of my react app even on the `/storybook` url. What am I doing wrong in this config. I want react app to be rendered on `/` but storybook if user is specifying `/storybook` in the url.

Comment: Since this is not your default service, do you have a ```dispatch.yaml``` file to route ```/storybook``` urls to this service?

Comment: I want to deploy two apps in the same service on two different routes

Answer (score 1):

The path `/storybook` does not match any handlers except `.*` because `/storybook/.*` needs slash (e.g. `/storybook/`).

Add a handler for `/storybook` like this.

```
  - url: /storybook
    static_files: storybook-static/index.html
    upload: storybook-static/index.html
    expiration: "0m"
    secure: always
```